# Tomcat RewriteRule error redirecting to homepage

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have the rewrite configuration as follows:
Code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).p$ /ProductFe?name=$1 [QSA][L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.jsp [L]
```

Khi gõ địa chỉ url
http://localhost/ecommerce/a.p =>It worked correctly move to ProductFe
http://localhost/ecommerce =>wants to go to the homepage but it still redirects to ProductFe.
I don't know where I went wrong please help me

Comment: In what _context_ are you using these directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*).p$ /ProductFe?name=$1 [QSA][L]
> RewriteRule ^/$ /index.jsp [L]
> ```

The second rule rewrites the request to `/index.jsp`, but then (during the second pass of the rewrite engine) the *first* rule rewrites `/index.jsp` to `/ProductFe?name=/index.j` since `/index.jsp` matches the regex `^(.*).p$` (the second dot is not backslash-escaped so matches any character). If the second dot is intended to match a literal dot then it needs to be backslash-escaped. eg. `^(.*)\.p$`

The flag argument on the first rule, ie. `[QSA][L]` is also incorrectly formatted. This should read `[QSA,L]`.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.p$ /ProductFe?name=$1 [QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.jsp [END]
```